# Prove a function is harmonic(use Green formula)

Tags: analysis

A real valued function $u$, defined in the unit disk, $D_1$ is harmonic if
it satisfies the partial differential equation $\partial_{xx} u +\partial_{yy} u = 0$. Prove that a
such function $u$ defined in $D_1$ is harmonic if and only if for each $(x, y) ∈ D_1$

$$
u(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}u(x+r~\cos{(\theta)},y+r~\sin{(\theta)})d\theta
$$

for sufficiently small positive $r$.Hint: Recall Green’sformula: 
$$
\int_{D} \Delta u dA=\int_{b D}\partial_v\nu ds
$$
I have no ideas on this question. Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Take $u$ harminic, and a point in $D_1$. Apply Green's formula to $u$ and a little circle around the point. Since $\Delta u = 0$, the right side vanishes. The boundary of the little disc can be parametrized as in the integral above that equals $u.$

Comment: May I ask you what is the textbook from which this exercice is taken ?

Comment: @VictorZurkowski the Green formula is: $\iint_{D} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} dxdy=\oint_{bD}Pdx+Qdy$ Can you tell me where is the $u$ in this formula? Since there are two functions P and Q in the left side

Comment: @JeanMarie it's taken from preliminary exams of University of Pennsylvania.

Comment: $Q=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $P=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ so  $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \Delta u = 0.$

Comment: @VictorZurkowski And then I can get $=\oint_{bD}U_y dx-U_x dy$, can you tell me how to reach the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Green's formula $\iint_{D} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} dxdy=\oint_{bD}Pdx+Qdy$, take $Q=u_x$, $P=-u_y$, and $D$ a small circle of radious r centered at $(x_0,y_0)$. We get:

$$ \iint_{D} \Delta u \space dA = \oint_{\partial D} \nabla u \cdot (dy,-dx) .$$

If we parametrized the boundary of $D$ as:
$$ \begin{equation}
x(\theta) = x_0 + r\cos(\theta) \\
y(\theta) = y_0 + r\sin(\theta) \\
\end{equation} $$
then 
$$ (dy,-dx) = r (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)) d\theta = r \nu d\theta $$
where $\nu$ is the exterior normal to $\partial D$, so the Green's formula you mentioned implies the formula in the problem suggestion.

Since $u$ is harmonic, the left side is $0$ and we get:
$$ 0 = \oint_{\partial D} \nabla u \cdot (dy,-dx)=\\
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \{u_x(x_0 +r\cos(\theta), y_0 + r\sin(\theta)) r\cos(\theta) + \\
\space u_y(x_0 +r\cos(\theta), y_0 + r\sin(\theta)) r\sin(\theta)\} \space d\theta $$

Now we compare what we have and what we want to get. Let me point some obvious facts (hind side is 20/20...) :
* the last formula involves derivatives of $u$, but the problem has only $u$, without derivatives, which suggest we will need to differentiate something
* the right side of the formula involves $r$, but the left side has no $r$, so its derivative with respect to $r$ is $0$

You can give it the final kick.

$$\dots\dots\dots$$
Now we observed that
$$ 0 = r \space \int_{0}^{2\pi} \{u_x(x_0 +r\cos(\theta), y_0 + r\sin(\theta)) \cos(\theta) + \\
\space u_y(x_0 +r\cos(\theta), y_0 + r\sin(\theta)) \sin(\theta)\} \space d\theta =\\
= r \space \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \int_{0}^{2\pi} u(x_0 +r\cos(\theta), y_0 + r\sin(\theta)) \space d\theta .$$
Therefor the integral over the boundary of the little circle is constant, and the  value can be found by taking limit as $r \rightarrow 0^+$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Why don't you divide $r$ in the both side of your last equation, since the left side is 0. And I think we cannot differentiate $u$ with respect to $r$ because $r$ is a sufficient small number(not variable) but I cannot get useful results by  differentiate $u$ with respect to $x$ or $y$

Comment: I'll edit the answer

Comment: Sorry. I had a wrong sign... I corrected it now.

Comment: I supplement the final proof: $0= \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \int_{0}^{2\pi} u(x_0 +r\cos(\theta), y_0 + r\sin(\theta)) \space d\theta $ means $Cu(x_0,y_0)=\int_{0}^{2\pi} u(x_0 +r\cos(\theta), y_0 + r\sin(\theta)) \space d\theta$ (C is a constant) and then by $r \rightarrow 0^+$, we can get $Cu(x_0,y_0)=2\pi u(x_0,y_0)$ which indicates $C=2\pi$. And this is the final argument of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple proof of the mean-value theorem for harmonic functions of two variables.  We start with [Green's Third Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities#Green.27s_third_identity)

$$u(\vec x_0)=\oint_C \left(u(\vec x')\frac{\partial G(\vec x_0,\vec x')}{\partial n'}-G(\vec x_0,\vec x')\frac{\partial u(\vec x')}{\partial n'}\right)\,d \ell' \tag 1$$

where $u(\vec x)$ is harmonic in a region $S$ bounded by the smooth contour $C$ and $G(\vec x_0,\vec x')=\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|\vec x_0-\vec x'|$ is the Green's Function for the Laplacian.

If we choose $S$ to be the region $|\vec x_0-\vec x'|\le r$, and thus $C$ to be the circle of radius $r$ and center $\vec x_0$, then on $C$ we have

$$\begin{align}
G(\vec x_0,\vec x')&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\log(r) \tag 2\\\\
\frac{\partial G(\vec x_0,\vec x')}{\partial n'}&=\frac{1}{2\pi r} \tag 3
\end{align}$$

Using $(2)$ and $(3)$ in $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
u(\vec x_0)&=\frac{1}{2\pi r}\oint_C u(\vec x')\,d\ell'-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log(r)\oint_C \frac{\partial u(\vec x')}{\partial n'}d \ell' \tag 4\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi r}0\int_C u(\vec x')\,d\ell'-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log(r)\int_{S} \nabla '\cdot \nabla 'u(\vec x')\,dS' \tag 5\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi r}\oint_C u(\vec x')\,d\ell'-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log(r)\int_{S} \nabla '^2 u(\vec x')\,dS' \\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi r}\oint_C u(\vec x')\,d\ell' \tag 6\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_0^{2\pi} u(x_0+r\cos(\phi),y_0+r\sin(\phi))\,d\phi
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

In going from $(4)$ to $(5)$, we invoked the Divergence Theorem, while in arriving at $(6)$ we used the fact that $u$ is harmonic.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed proof! I'm now preparing for a preliminary exam and I think the method of VictorZurkowski is a little bit easier for me to master and it's also the method of the Hint in this problem. Your method is also very useful for me because the three Green Identity serve as the bond to physical and engineering problems. I will learning them later after I pass the qualified exam of my school. Thank you again for your answer!

Comment: Xinyu, please feel free to up vote this answer.  ;-))  -Mark